# How to handle graph relationship in data warehouse?

Tags: database, data-warehouse

Imagine we have many companies and they are related to each other by relationships like "A is a buyer of B", "B is a seller of A", "C is a subsidiary of B", etc.

We may use a graph database to handle those relationships. But in a typical data warehouse environment (table format), how can we represent those relationships effectively?

Currently, I am thinking of using a relationship table to store relationships between companies and a separate table for storing company attributes.

Comment: Why not use a Graph database? Use a hammer for nails, but a screwdriver for screws. You may be trying too hard to fit a square peg in a round hole.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming we are talking about generic relationships rather than hierarchies - which are a very specific type of relationship)

In a Data Warehouse, Company data would be held in a Dimension table and (apart from some special cases) you don't relate Dimensions to each other directly: they are related to each other via a fact table.

Where a fact has more than one relationship to the same dimension then you just have multiple FKs in the Fact pointing to the Dimension (Role-playing dimensions). So for a transactional fact you might have a Buyer FK, a Seller FK, etc. all referencing records in the Company dimension.

If your relationships have any real level of complexity then, as the previous comment states, you would be much better off using a graph DB if you need to report on those relationships.

If you have a limited number of relationship types and each relationship type has a fixed cardinality then you might be able to model it in a factless fact table i.e. a fact table that just contains FKs to the Company dimension. In order to get this to work in any useful way, as a starting point you'd probably need to be able to define a single core role and then show the relationships to that role. For example, you might start with a Subsidiary for each fact record and then show the related Parent, Buyer, etc. to that Subsidiary